# Add Padding to TabView Page Indicator

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, user-experience

I have a view that is a TabView with the style `PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always` which looks great for my use case however the page indicator is bumping right up to the safe area near the bottom of the screen and it looks bad. I'd like to move the page indicator up to some `n` value. here's a sample of my view to reproducing it. If this view were built on any device without a Home Button, it will ride on top of the home indicator line.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        TabView(selection: $homeVM.selectedPageIndex) {
            // Any number of views here.
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

I attempted to add the padding to the ZStack, which does work but then my TabView is cut off on the bottom, which means my cells disappear prematurely.

Here's an image for what I'm trying to fix. Notice the page indicator sits on the home bar indicator. I need the indicators pushed up, without pushing up the background ScrollView

[image]

#### Update #1

This view is being presented by a base view that I use to handle my navigation stack. The view is as follows. The important thing to note here is the `.ignoresSafeArea()` that I have on this view. I did that because it's a containing view for my eventual TabView to be presented from. Interestingly if I remove this modifier the indicators move up to a more manageable position, but then my form becomes clipped at the top and bottom of the device when scrolling, and that's not ideal.

```
struct BaseLaunchView: View {
    @StateObject var baseNavVM = BaseLaunchViewModel()
    @State var shouldLogin = false
    @State var shouldRegister = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch baseNavVM.loggedIn {
            case true:
                HomeView()
            default:
                NavigationView {
                    VStack{
                        Spacer()

                        VStack(spacing: 30) {
                            VStack {
                                Text("Stello")
                                    .font(Fonts.title)
                                Text("Life Groups")
                                    .font(Fonts.body)
                            }

                            StelloDivider()

                            Text("Connect with like minded people, to fellowship and find your home.")
                                .font(Fonts.subheading)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        }

                        Spacer()

                        NavigationLink(destination: RegisterOptionsView(isLoggingIn: true), isActive: $shouldLogin) {
                            Button(action: {
                                shouldLogin.toggle()
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Login")
                                    .font(Fonts.button)
                            }).buttonStyle(StelloFillButtonStyle())
                        }

                        NavigationLink(destination: RegisterOptionsView(isLoggingIn: false), isActive: $shouldRegister) {
                            Button(action: {
                                shouldRegister.toggle()
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Register")
                                    .font(Fonts.button)
                            }).buttonStyle(StelloHollowButtonStyle())
                        }
                    }
                }.accentColor(.black)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .environmentObject(baseNavVM)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to parse this out and I am not entirely sure of the issue yet. I am gathering that the "// Any number of views here" actually need all of the screen real estate because of some fixed sizes or something? So, when you try to move the view up, you are losing some of your UI? Can you show an image of the problem and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Yrb added a pic. The `// any views` is irrelevant to the issue from what I can tell. I've been able to reproduce it with regular `Text('hello, world")` views.

Comment: Oh and yes, I need to view to take up the entire space. It might be that I should use some other List style, but I'm thinking this is what I should have for what I'm doing.

Comment: I am not having that problem when I apply your settings to a tabview that I have. At this point, I think needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to dig into specifically what you are doing.

Comment: @Yrb added more context after your comment. I found the difference that causes it to be reproducable. The containing view has `.ignoresSafeArea` modifier.